# Gitlab CI - using git across different jobs

Tags: git, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I know that every `gitlab ci job` has been specifically designed to not depend on any other (so they can be ran separately).

However, I need to do something different, and this is my current pipeline:

```
1. install dependencies
2. lint
3. commit linted files // <== first commit
4. test
5. bump versions; commit and tag repository // <== second commit
6. compile
7. push tags and commits back to the origin // <== push tags
```

#### How could I preserve the status of git across different jobs?

Ideally, I will push those commits and tags only after I know the build has passed. And also the second commit should be made on top of the first one...

Current behaviour is:

Since every job starts from scratch the changes made, but not pushed, to the repo will be lost...

Answer (score 0):

You should probably take a look at [dependencies](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#dependencies) in GitLab CI.

Comment: could you please elaborate a bit more

Comment: I think you could try sharing the whole git-repository through the different jobs.

Comment: A workaround I have put is adding `.git` to `cache:paths`, any thought on side effects I could get?